# An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-9'

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I'm new to cognos and i got this error when i try view the data in tabular form (run-> View Tabular Data) the following condition

```
if ( [daysbetween]< 11)
 then (1) 
else (0)
```

when i validate the expression it shows no error

I know there is another question here but i didn't find the solution for my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this expression as a condition just leave

```
[daysbetween]< 11
```

in filter.

If you use it as a Data Item, check other parts of you report

Comment: i'm using it as a data item

Comment: is the error related to any flaws during configuration??

Comment: Does your report run without this field? Many different things lead to "Status = -9". Please, post detailed error description.
Btw, what type of [daysbetween]?

Comment: UDA-SQL-0450 An unexpected error encountered during the "prepare" operation.UDA-SQL-0516 The Informix server returned the following message: "It is not possible to convert between the specified types.".

Comment: So check [daysbetween] type. Is it or some kind of interval or date.